# How can I find only one distinct digit in a cell in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have customer data with mobile phone numbers where '1' has been entered 10 times or more in a cell to bypass the customer onboarding system validation. For example '1111111111'

I used below condition in my where clause but that didn't really help.

```
AND p.mobile_no LIKE '%[1111111111]%'
```

It is possible that users might enter 1 multiple number of times in the new customer form to bypass validation. To find only 0 values in the cell I used %[^0]% in the WHERE clause and I was hoping to use something similar to find 1s where regardless of how many times it has been entered in the field, as long as it only has 1 in it it will skim out the data for me.

How can I find these instances in my data using a SQL query?

The goal is to find these anomalies and remove them.

Using: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2).

Comment: And why are you using `[]` - just remove them.

Comment: Did you try `'%1111111111%'`?

Comment: Thanks @DaleK, I am new to the SQL scene therefore didn't realise the difference.

Comment: Hi @DaleK I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (Management Studio)

Comment: FYI SSMS is just the client interface... for reporting the version (unless its an issue specific to SSMS) you need to show the engine version e.g. `select @@version`.

Comment: Hi @forpas thanks for responding. I did try that but it didn't return a result however I have been advised by the business that there are instances of invalid phone number with only one type of digits used in the field.

Comment: Hi @DaleK thanks a lot, your query returned 'Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2)'

Comment: Hi @forpas apologies for causing the confusion. It is possible that users might enter 1 multiple number of times in the new customer form to bypass validation. To find only 0 values in the cell I used %[^0]% in the WHERE clause and I was hoping to use something similar to find 1s where regardless of how many times it has been entered in the field, as long as it only has 1 in it it will skim out the data for me.

Comment: Hi @DaleK, Appreciate your feedback. I am new to stackoverflow as well therefore l am learning may way around this tool as I go along.  You are correct, I am looking for 1s, with any number of length. The UI only accepts numbers but does not have restriction on the length or what is a valid mobile phone number. In Australia our mobile phone numbers consist of 10 digit starting and always begin with a zero.

Comment: @9684921 its not really anything related to this tool. Its about how you, as a developer, communicate issues with others (just think of when you receive a bug report from a user and struggle to make sense of it). The people you are communicating with cannot read your mind, therefore you need to express your requirements as clearly as possible, in as much detail as possible, making no assuming about what they do/do not already know. Anyway see my answer below.

Comment: Point noted.  Thanks @DaleK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the following, which tests if at least 1 '1' exists, and that no other characters exist.

```
select Number
from (values ('111'),('121'),('1-2'),('22')) x (Number)
-- Test that at least 1 '1' exists
where Number like '%1%'
-- And that no other allowable characters exist - expand to cover all options
and Number not like '%[0,2-9,-]%'
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Dale for persevering with me. I tried your logic and it didn't return any match which leads me to believe that there are not instances with only 1 being entered in the mobile phone number field. However some other consulting agency used by the business highlighted this issue without providing the sample data hence the reason I was looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a table to define invalid phone numbers:

```
 Declare @invalidPhoneNumbers Table (PhoneNumber char(10));
  Insert Into @testData (PhoneNumber)
  Values ('0000000000'), ('1111111111'), ('2222222222'), ('3333333333'), ('4444444444')
       , ('5555555555'), ('6666666666'), ('7777777777'), ('8888888888'), ('9999999999');

 Select ...
   From ...
  Where ...
    And p.mobile_no Not In (Select i.PhoneNumber From @invalidPhoneNumbers i)
```

Or - using NOT EXISTS which may perform better:

```
 Declare @invalidPhoneNumbers Table (PhoneNumber char(10));
  Insert Into @testData (PhoneNumber)
  Values ('0000000000'), ('1111111111'), ('2222222222'), ('3333333333'), ('4444444444')
       , ('5555555555'), ('6666666666'), ('7777777777'), ('8888888888'), ('9999999999');

 Select ...
   From ...
  Where ...
    And Not Exists (Select * From @invalidPhoneNumbers i Where i.PhoneNumber = p.mobile_no)
```

When declaring the table - make sure the data type defined matches exactly the defined data type of p.mobile_no.  This will make sure there are no implicit conversions that can cause issues.